# Unable to Remove \\u0000 From String

Tags: c#

I am calling an API that returns a string with the following information: `"abc \\u0000\\u0000 fjkdshf"`. I have tried removing this using the following code but it doesn't seem to work.

```
string res = str.Replace("\\", string.Empty)
    .Replace("u0000", string.Empty)
    .Trim();
```

I have read in a couple of articles that this string doesn't actually display when you are not debugging using Visual Studio so I don't know how to fix this problem. Please help!

Comment: How are you checking this string? The `\\uXXXX` values are usually shorthand for unicode characters. Rather than the text `\\u0000` you may have null terminator characters, and the tool you're using to view the data is showing the unicode value for any unprintable text.

Comment: Try `str.Replace("\u0000", string.Empty)` or `str.Replace("\0", string.Empty)`.

Comment: The string is actually showing on our logs in CosmosDB which I assume shows the unicode value of the null terminator character. How can I remove this?

Comment: @41686d6564, it doesn't work because my string contains two backslashes, not one.

Comment: @Josh Did you try it or are you just speculating that it _won't_ work? Note that `"\u0000"` is a null terminator character and it might get displayed as `"\\u0000"` in certain situations. A literal `"\\u0000"` in C#, on the other hand, means "a slash character followed by the letter "u", followed by four zeros.

Comment: @41686d6564, I tried your solution when debugging VS but it didn't work. I'm going to deploy our application and see if what you said will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you mistake the double backslash as actual characters. They are displayed in the debugger because the second backslash is escaped and the first is used as an [escape charachter](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/371232/Escaping-in-Csharp-characters-strings-string-forma). if you want to replace it simply use `"\u0000"`.

Here is an examplary programm that prints the UTF code of each character

```
void Main()
{
    string s = "abc \u0000\u0000 fjkdshf";
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", s.Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x))));

    string res = s.Replace("\u0000", string.Empty);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", res.Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x))));       
}
```

Output:

> 97 98 99 32 `0 0` 32 102 106 107 100 115 104 102
> 97 98 99 32 32 102 106 107 100 115 104 102

as you can see in the output, after the replacement the zeros are gone!

More information about [literal string escaping](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/371232/Escaping-in-Csharp-characters-strings-string-forma)